# MVC Razor how to get option value from form and set viewmodel property to selected value

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core

When filling out a form the user gets a prompt to choose a specific option from a dropdown menu. The selected option should, along with the rest of the inputs, be sent to my controller to handle the data.

Now I'm stuck as to how I send the selected option.

I want to take the selected station and send its Id to my controller to be used for creating a new plant.

What I would want is to do something like this:
`<input asp-for="stationId" value=@selectedStation.Id">` but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get the selected option station and set the stationId value for the model to it when posting the form.

```
<form asp-controller="Plant" asp-action="Create" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Station</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="stationId">
            @foreach (var station in Model.Stations)
            {
                <option>@station.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

the view model used for the form:

```
 public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int StationId { get; set; }
        public List<Station> Stations { get; set; }
```

And finally the controller action:

```
[Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(CreatePlantViewModel createPlant)
        {
            var plant = new Plant
            {
                StationId = createPlant.StationId,
                Description = createPlant.Description,
                Name = createPlant.Name
            };
            _context.Add(plant);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

EDIT:
With help from stack overflow user this was what was needed to change in the select element for stations:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Station</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="stationId" asp-for="StationId">
            @foreach (var station in Model.Stations)
            {
                <option value="@station.Id">@station.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is linked to the fact that no values are being sent to the controller. 
The following :

```
<option>@station.Name</option>
```

Should be :

```
//Assuming that your station class has an id
<option value = "@station.id">@station.Name</option>
```

You can also do it this way :

```
<select id="stationId" asp-for="stationId" asp-items=@(new SelectList(Model.Stations, "stationId", "Name")) class="form-control"></select>
```

Comment: Thank you!

Setting just the value however didn't do it. I also had to set `asp-for="StationId"` in the surrounding select element. Appreciate the help a lot!

Comment: @Gurkmeja101 Glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Razor for this, i find it helps to keep track of what you are doing:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StationId, --Value will be assigned to this variable
                     new SelectList(
                         Model.Stations, 
                         "stationId", 
                         "Name"), --List of values will come from here
                     "-Select Station-", --The default value
                     new {id="stationId",class="Form-control" } -- Attributes you would assignin HTML
    )
```